# How to send JSON to a Web API?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I'm making a website with web API, I tried to send JSON to my controller but this is the error I keep getting.

```
 Multiple actions were found that match the request:
 Post on type AuctionWebsiteASP.Controllers.MovesController
 readDatabase on type AuctionWebsiteASP.Controllers.MovesController
 newItem on type AuctionWebsiteASP.Controllers.MovesController
```

First I tried searching for a fix but none of the fixes here helped.

My Controller

```
public class MovesController : ApiController
{
    [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Product product)
    {
        products.Add(product);
        newItem();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, product);
    }
 }
```

My JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/api/moves/",
    data: source,
    success: function (data) {
        $("#nStart").val(null);
        $("#nImg").val(null);
        $("#nMaker").val(null);
        $("#nModel").val(null);
        $("#nSerial").val(null);
        $("#nCpu").val(null);
        $("#nRam").val(null);
        $("#nGpu").val(null);
        $("#nStorage").val(null);
        $("#nBattery").val(null);
        $("#nDrivers").val(null);
        $("#nAccessories").val(null);
        $("#nNotes").val(null);
        console.log("Data has been sent!");
    },
    error: function (error) {
        jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(error.responseText);
        alert("ERROR!");
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Product product)` only method in the controller?

Comment: No, it isnt i tried using the `Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }` and added the action to the url but didnt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route is probably like this

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "API Default",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

But in order to have multiple actions with the same http method you need to provide webapi with more information via the route like so:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "API Default",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Try to use `Route` attribute to distinguish each action e.g

```
 public class MovesController : ApiController
 {
     [Route("Product")]
     public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Product product)
     {
         products.Add(product);
         newItem();
         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, product);
     }
  }
```

`$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/api/moves/product",
    data: source,
    success: function (data) {
        $("#nStart").val(null);
        $("#nImg").val(null);
        $("#nMaker").val(null);
        $("#nModel").val(null);
        $("#nSerial").val(null);
        $("#nCpu").val(null);
        $("#nRam").val(null);
        $("#nGpu").val(null);
        $("#nStorage").val(null);
        $("#nBattery").val(null);
        $("#nDrivers").val(null);
        $("#nAccessories").val(null);
        $("#nNotes").val(null);
        console.log("Data has been sent!");
    },
    error: function (error) {
        jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(error.responseText);
        alert("ERROR!");
    }
});`

Comment: then try to use `Route` attribute

Comment: What is the namespace for `[Route("Product")]` ?

Comment: Install-Package AttributeRouting (for MVC)

Comment: Install-Package AttributeRouting.WebApi (for Web API)

Comment: I am using ajax to call my post method in controllers. What should i use?

Comment: It works only on MVC install and not WebApi. But still i get the Internal server Error 500. `Multiple actions were found`